# Why am I having these errors, when opening my Unity project in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, linux

I'm experiencing some trouble with the Linux build of Unity. I suspect that my Nvidia driver is producing this error, but I'm really not sure. I have an Nvidia GTX 860M, and until 2 days ago, I was able to use Unity without any problems. I have not touched my computer in those 2 days. My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

This is the error that I get in my editor log:

> ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(148)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandB$
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(256)] Failed to $
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(148)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandB$
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(256)] Failed to $
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(148)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandB$
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(256)] Failed to $
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(148)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandB$
>   [1010/122616:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(256)] Failed to $
>   ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
>   /home/MyUser/Unity3d/Age
>   UpdateMenuTitleForLanguage: 10
>   Receiving unhandled NULL exception
>   Launching bug reporter

Why am I having these errors, when opening my Unity project in Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you maybe use unity 5.2 on windows and then port it to linux? That may be the problem.

Comment: I'm using the Linux build for unity3d and i don't have any Windows installed

Answer (score 0):

While only a broad explanation for future users, Unity does not actually currently support Linux or Ubuntu. Looking at [the system requirements page](https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements), Linux is not listed as a supported platform; furthermore, it is not listed as an available platform in [the archive for previous builds](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive).

> ### System Requirements for Unity 5.6
>
> #### For development
>
> **OS:** Windows 7 SP1+, 8, 10; Mac OS X 10.8+.
> <sub>[- Official Unity system requirements page](https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements)</sub>

---

As far as I was aware, there *is* a version of Unity available for Linux and Ubunutu; however, they are not *officially* supported. I have previously found versions on the official website, but even in these cases, the developers acknowledged that said versions were buggy. I can not find these versions, now; perhaps I have missed them, perhaps they have been taken down.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the answers did mention, Linux is ***not officially supported***.
We get those releases just because Unity development team is kind enough to give us at least something. Imagine an endless number of distributions and libraries and kernels they have to support if they announce it - that's like digging your own grave.
Your best bet is to get latest release, Unity 2017 as of recently
(https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/)
And do try latest Ubuntu, since big chances are Unity team is using it.
Just to prove that Unity is actually doing *some* work on Linux releases, refer to the state of Unreal Engine. Unreal does not even provide releases for Linux. The only way is to build it from source and see that it's basically unusable: graphical artifacts, 100% cpu load and silky-smooth 10 fps.

Comment: 2 years ago question, buddy

Comment: @Max duh, looks like it was automatically bumped since no accepted answer. Did not check dates, sorry

Comment: @Max, if you cant resolve the question, you should probably delete it.

Comment: Agree with you @Gnemlock, but I'm not able to delete this.

Comment: @Max, neither answer has a positive score. There is nothing to stop you deleting this.

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center"